# Why does my git personal website not match the local display? Image loss

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. And I am trying to build a personal website using github's free hostname. Somehow, even after I did everything, git pull add commit push, some of the images and videos won't display in browser. But the files themselves are successfully uploaded to that repository.

Here is a picture of the pictures missing looking like this
[image]

But when i go back to the repository to check, all the image files are there.

I don't know what went wrong. Any suggestion would be helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that those images are hardlinked to a location on your computer instead of a relational link?

Comment: They are in a separate directory. And when I uploaded the file everything within it was also uploaded. Also everything was alright in the local file.

Comment: So it is like <img src = "xx/yy.jpg" > </img>

Comment: Could you share a link to your repository?

Comment: @RimilDey https://github.com/catherinedu1997/catherinedu1997.github.io Thank you so much. I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your images in the directory are capitalised (as in CAT55.jpg etc.,), but the src attribute of your pictures are in lower case (like `src="cat55.jpg"`). Locally, there is no distinction between upper and lower case letters, but they are treated separately by the server. That's why you see the images offline on your machine, but they aren't displayed when you see it online.

You can either fix the names of the image files and change them all to lower case, or change the src attributes to link them to names that are all uppercase (exactly how the image files are named). That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the images still wouldn't load?

Comment: I changed the src attributes of the images to match **exactly** the names you have specified for the images, and they are loading. Change the src attributes it will work. I tried it out myself. You can check here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/check/gallery.html